# autocorrect the whole math equations within ms-word

Tags: math, ms-word, formulas, mathml, equations

I have written a plain text in notepad editor. This text contains some embedded mathematical formulas like \sumw_if(x_i) which refers to [\sumw_if(x_i)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXOKN.jpg) or \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2 which refers to [\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/877td.jpg)etc.
Now, I'm looking for a way to autocorrect all those formulas within ms-word. First I tought to select formulas one by one and then "ALT +" to get the maths notation. This method works fine but it's frustrating because I have a bunch of equations

Is there any help? Macros, MathML or other tips?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "autocorrect"?  Are you wanting Word to automatically correct misspellings like \usm to \sum?  That's a pretty difficult problem, and bound to give you many headaches when Word misguesses.  Or are you wanting to perform a global search and replace?

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded mathematical formulas were delimited with dollar signs -- e.g., $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2$ -- MathType can do it with its Toggle TeX feature. If it's something you want to do programmatically, there's the [MathType SDK](http://dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/default.htm).